# new Date(milliseconds) returns Invalid date

Tags: javascript, date, time, milliseconds

I am trying to convert milliseconds to a date using the javascript using:

```
new Date(Milliseconds);
```

constructor, but when I give it a milliseconds value of say 1372439683000 it returns invalid date. If I go to a [site that converts milliseconds to date](http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/) it returns the correct date.

Any ideas why?

Comment: `alert(new Date(1372439683000));` works for me. What do you mean by "invalid date" exactly, what result are you getting?

Comment: @Pekka웃 The OP is getting a `Date` object that stringifies to "`Invalid Date`". (e.g., try out `alert(new Date(""))`)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You're not using a number, you're using a *string* that looks like a number. According to MDN, when you pass a string into [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), it expects

> a format recognized by the parse method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps).

An example of such a string is "`December 17, 1995 03:24:00`", but you're passing in a string that looks like "`1372439683000`", which is not able to be parsed.

Convert `Milliseconds` to a number using `parseInt`, or a unary `+`:

```
new Date(+Milliseconds); 
new Date(parseInt(Milliseconds,10));
```

Comment: `new Date(929397621000)` in Developer Tools returns a validly formatted date string  `Mon Jun 14 1999 15:00:21 GMT-0700 (PDT)` yet when I try to inspect the object, it shows "Invalid Date".  And in the actual code where this is being used, it also creates an invalid date.

Comment: @Michael This appears to be a different issue from the one described here. Are you doing `console.dir(new Date(929397621000))`? If so, seeing `__proto__: Invalid Date` inside that instance is correct (or at least unsurprising) behavior. The `Date` *prototype* *is* an invalid date; valid date information exists on `Date` *instances*, not on the prototype.

Comment: I'm entering the expression directly as a watch in Chrome's developer tools.  My code is basically doing the same thing.  Since I'm calling `new` that should produce a valid Date object, yes?  Strangely, even `new Date()` is producing an invalid date (that the debugger can strangely stringify correctly) which I cannot inspect the elements of (because it only shows "Invalid Date") so maybe it is a cockpit issue.

Comment: Well, it appears that the problem only occurs in the inspector... the actual object is valid, even though inspecting the object shows it is invalid.

Comment: @Michael Your issues appears to be nuanced enough to merit a new question post (or bug report?)

Comment: nah, it turned out the problem was a string being passed in (for some reason, the variable was supposed to be a number, but why it isn't is for a separate debug session) but then after i fixed it i was trying to verify it in the debugger, and ran across this Chrome issue/quirk - doesn't really cause any harm, just made me think the bug wasn't fixed.

Comment: In my case I was fetching the data and it came as 1.495462321562E12. It was a string and hence I tried to convert it to int and it failed. The actual thing to do there was parseFloat().

Answer (score 5):

The `Date` function is case-sensitive:

```
new Date(Milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is important to note that the timestamp parameter *MUST* be a number, it cannot be a string.

```js
new Date(1631793000000).toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires' });

// Returns: '16/09/2021, 08:50:00'

new Date("1631793000000").toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires' });

// Returns: 'Invalid Date'
```

In case you're receiving the timestamp as string, you can simply wrap it around *parseInt()*: `parseInt(your_ts_string)`

Answer (score 1):

instead of this

```
new date(Milliseconds);
```

use this

```
new Date(Milliseconds);
```

your statement will give you *date is not defined* error

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error due to a different reason.

I read a key from redis whose value is a json.

`client.get(someid, function(error, somevalue){});`

Now i was trying to access the fields inside `somevalue` (which is a string), like `somevalue.start_time`, without parsing to JSON object.
This was returning "undefined" which if passed to Date constructor, `new Date(somevalue.start_time)` returns "Invalid date".

So first using `JSON.parse(somevalue)` to get JSON object before accessing fields inside the json solved the problem.