# How to convert milliseconds to date and time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I know this question has been asked and answered many times, but I could not convert a given milliseconds to date and time.

I have the following code:

```
var date = '1475235770601';
var d = new Date(date);
var ds = d.toLocaleString();
alert(ds);
console.log(ds);
```

When I run this I see **Invalid Date** in console as well as in alert.

But when I paste the milliseconds [here](https://currentmillis.com/), it converts fine in the format in local date and time as `Fri Sep 30 2016 17:12:50`.

Actually I want to convert in in the format `09/30/16 17:12:50`.

Comment: Hi people saw this just now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371302/new-datemilliseconds-returns-invalid-date

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Date`'s constructor takes a number, not a string. Either feed it in directly:

```
date = 1475235770601; // Note the lack of quotes making it a number
```

Or, if you already have a string, convert it explicitly:

```
date = parseInt(date);
```

Comment: "*Date's constructor takes a number, not a string*". Not true, that should be "*The Date constructor takes **either** a number or a string*", it's behaviour changes depending on what it's given.

Answer (score 8):

I ended up changing my code like this:

```
var date = '1475235770601';
var d = new Date(parseInt(date, 10));
var ds = d.toString('MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss');
console.log(ds);
```

Output:

```
09/30/16 17:12:50
```

Answer (score 2):

I got quite a reasonable result with:

```
const rawDate = new Date(milliseconds)
const date = rawDate.toLocaleDateString() + " " + rawDate.toLocaleTimeString()
```

This outputs date and time in a locally accepted format (depending on user system datetime settings, I guess)!

So if you need just a locally accepted format (and do not strictly prefer slashes in the date) - you can use that.